# How can aws boto3 submit a final batch job that depends on the completion of all previous jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing, boto3

The boto3 [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.submit_job) describes how to submit a `dependsOn` parameter, but a single job can only depend on the completion of a maximum of 20 jobs. How can I submit a job that depends on the completion of an arbitrarily large number of jobs? Can this be done by specifying the final job type as `SEQUENTIAL`? Or does this need to be done by creating a lower priority queue?

Answer (score 1):

While AWS Batch does limit you to 20 arbitrary jobs (you can contract them to see about bumping it), they did introduce array jobs in November 2017.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/array_jobs.html

This when you want the same basic job step run on a number of machines (i.e. not totally arbitrary jobs). So it takes that one job and can break it into up to 10,000 jobs. Each is given an index parameter so you could pass a large document and have each final job work on a given page number.

Then your next job step could be dependent on that job that had 2-10,000 jobs.

Check the documents for details, especially since you can configure the dependencies in different ways.